# Converting Multiple Polylines to Polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, polygon, convert, line

I have a shapefile for Parcels but the whole thing seems to be divided into polylines rather than polygons. I'm trying to create an existing land use map. I was hoping there is an easier way to convert multiple polylines to polygons rather than going through each one by one and merging them in editor?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Feature to Polygon (Data Management) tool

Comment: I don't think feature to polygon tool is the answer. That tool can create some odd results if you aren't careful where you want you're lines closed.

Comment: Im assuming the lines are the edges of the parcel, and share some parcel ID field. Using that tool will create parcel polygons with the parcel ID.

Comment: I can see that.

Answer (score 0):

QGIS has a Polygonize tool under the Vector Geometry tools section that is worth exploring, and can be used with different file types.

Comment: ArcGIS specific question